# In quantlib (python), is there a way to specify settlementdays for a swapratehelper without having to also give discountCurve?

Tags: quantlib

Using the following Python code I am setting USD LIBOR Swap quotes. I found that by default settlementdays uses whatever is associated with the Index (in C++:
`if (settlementDays_==Null<Natural>()) settlementDays_ = iborIndex->fixingDays();`). If I wanted to explicitly set `settlementDays = 0`, how can I do that? I tried just use `settlementDays = 0`, but the code does not seem to like named argument here. How would I go about setting that without having to also specify `discountCurve`?

I do not want to use a different curve, and don't quite understand how I can reference a curve that does not yet exist. 
Thank you in advance!

```
s_helpers = [ SwapRateHelper(rate/100.0,
                       tenor, l_calendar,
                       Semiannual, l_pmt_conv, 
                       Thirty360(), 
                       USDLibor(Period(3, Months)))

        for tenor, rate in [(Period(1,Years), 2.395),
                            (Period(2,Years), 2.575),
                            (Period(3,Years), 2.651),
                            (Period(5,Years), 2.704),
                            (Period(7,Years), 2.734),
                            (Period(10,Years), 2.779),
                            (Period(30,Years), 2.822)] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So one cannot omit arguments in these Python functions, since they aren't exposed as keyword arguments. Instead I ended up created my own custom LIBOR index with 0 settlement days and used that in swap rate helper:

s_helpers_0_sd = [ SwapRateHelper(rate/100.0,
                           tenor, calendar,
                           Semiannual, pmt_conv, 
                           Thirty360(), 
                           **Libor("USDLibor", Period(3, Months),0,USDCurrency(),NullCalendar(), Actual360())**)
            for tenor, rate in [(Period(1,Years), 2.395),
                                (Period(2,Years), 2.575),
                                (Period(3,Years), 2.651),
                                (Period(5,Years), 2.704),
                                (Period(7,Years), 2.734),
                                (Period(10,Years), 2.779),
                                (Period(30,Years), 2.822)] ]

I would still like to know what if it ever makes sense to specify the discountCurve parameter outside of cases where I would actually have different discount and forecast curves?

Answer (score 0):

As in the source code, the default discount curve parameter is just a dummy YieldTermStructure handle so i believe this should work for you:

```
SwapRateHelper(rate/100.0,
                       tenor, l_calendar,
                       Semiannual, l_pmt_conv, 
                       Thirty360(), 
                       USDLibor(Period(3, Months)),
                       QuoteHandle(), Period(0, Days),
                       YieldTermStructureHandle(), 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the settlementDays parameter explicitly by passing it as an argument to the SwapRateHelper constructor. To do so, you can modify your code like this:

s_helpers = [ SwapRateHelper(rate/100.0,
tenor, l_calendar,
Semiannual, l_pmt_conv,
Thirty360(),
USDLibor(Period(3, Months)),
settlementDays=0)

```
    for tenor, rate in [(Period(1,Years), 2.395),
                        (Period(2,Years), 2.575),
                        (Period(3,Years), 2.651),
                        (Period(5,Years), 2.704),
                        (Period(7,Years), 2.734),
                        (Period(10,Years), 2.779),
                        (Period(30,Years), 2.822)] ]
```